# Get all paths in a graph from a node, but only ones which terminate

Tags: graph, gremlin, gremlinpython

I have written the following query which returns all paths possible from the specified node.

```
g.V(<some_id>).repeat(bothE().bothV().simplePath()).emit().dedup().path()
```

If we had a simple graph of 3 nodes in this structure:

```
A -- edge_1 -> B -- edge_2 -> C
```

this query would return two paths:

```
A, edge_1, B
A, edge_1, B, edge_2, C
```

However, I only want to return all paths that terminate (i.e. there is no further nodes to traverse), which in this example would only return

```
A, edge_1, B, edge_2, C
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the `repeat` without the `emit` step and use `until` to stop at the end of the path.

```
g.V().hasLabel('A').repeat(bothE().bothV().
    simplePath()).
  until(bothE().simplePath().
    count().is(eq(0))).dedup().path()
```

example: https://gremlify.com/jqr8y7p24wb

Comment: There are actually some instances where I am not getting the results I want, such as when there are loops in the graph. Here is one such example: https://gremlify.com/ccocxr1uau. Also to add to my original post, I want all nodes and all edges to be returned in the paths, but no one path returned should be a "sub-path" of another. Any ideas how to correct this?

Comment: @KOB in this case of a circle with different edges if you change the `bothE` to `both` you will get the routes https://gremlify.com/tja7crvmg4b

Comment: Ok it works, but I don't understand why the second path doesn't terminate at node 4, but instead continues to both nodes 3 and 2. Can you explian? Ideally I would want the second path just to have 1, D, 4 (i.e. returning the edge, D, that the first path didn't include. The first path already incldues 2, B, 3, C, so I don't need these returned in the second.

Comment: @KOB Because the two are distinguished by one edge from 1 to another, so no one is a subpath of the other, you need to consider if you really need to travel both directions and not going only on the out edges.

Comment: Ok I see. I don't need to travel in both directions. In short, all I need is the minimal amount of minimal length paths that collectively traverse all nodes and edges in the graph, if that makes sense? I am open to any other suggestions on queries that would achieve this